# Arrays of strings into numpy.amax

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In the Python's standard [`max`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max) function (I also can pass in a key parameter):

```py
s = numpy.array(['one','two','three'])
max(s) # 'two' (lexicographically last)
max(s, key=len) # 'three' (longest string)
```

With a larger (multi-dimensional) array, I can not longer use `max`, so I tried to use [`numpy.amax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html), however I can't seem to be able to use `amax` with strings...

```py
t = np.array([['one','two','three'],['four','five','six']])
t.dtype # dtype('|S5')
numpy.amax(t, axis=0) #Error! Hoping for: [`two`, `six`]

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 1833, in amax
        return amax(axis, out)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Is it possible to use `amax` (*am using it incorrectly!*), or is there some other `numpy` tool to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of storing your strings as variable length data in the `numpy` array, you could try storing them as Python `object`s instead. Numpy will treat these as references to the original Python string objects, and you can then treat them like you might expect:

```
t = np.array([['one','two','three'],['four','five','six']], dtype=object)
np.min(t)
# gives 'five'
np.max(t)
# gives 'two'
```

Keep in mind that here, the `np.min` and `np.max` calls are ordering the strings lexicographically - so "two" does indeed come after "five". To change the comparison operator to look at the length of each string, you could try creating a new `numpy` array identical in form, but containing each string's length instead of its reference. You could then do a `numpy.argmin` call on that array (which returns the index of the minimum) and look up the value of the string in the original array.

---

Example code:

```
# Vectorize takes a Python function and converts it into a Numpy
# vector function that operates on arrays
np_len = np.vectorize(lambda x: len(x))

np_len(t)
# gives array([[3, 3, 5], [4, 4, 3]])

idx = np_len(t).argmin(0) # get the index along the 0th axis
# gives array([0, 0, 1])

result = t
for i in idx[1:]:
    result = result[i]
print result
# gives "two", the string with the smallest length
```

Comment: Is there a reason why `dtype='|S5'` is the default rather than `'object'`? (I had thought it was the issue :) ). It seems copying the `t` for each `key` is going to create a lot of other arrays, especially when these arrays are huge, this seems like an indirect solution...

Comment: When you create a `numpy` array of strings, each is taken as a literal `numpy` string - just a number of consecutive bytes. As `numpy` arrays have to (or strive to) have the same size for each object, the default in this case is `'|S5'` - a string of length 5 - which is the longest string in your input.

Comment: If the input arrays are huge, well... yes, it is an indirect solution. Keep in mind that running `np_len(t).argmin(0)` doesn't save the intermediate array, although it still requires Python to iterate over each element in the interpreter.

Comment: Also (for the `key`), if `axis` is set then this is going to have to be slightly different (surely there is a built-in way...) I think I will ask this part as a separate question, which was actually my original question if this toy example had been behaving!