# In Numpy how to select elements based on the maximum of their absolute values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Basically I'd like to do the following Python equivalent for Numpy arrays of arbitrary dimension and specifying an arbitrary axis:

```
max(array, key=abs)
```

i.e. select elements based on the maximum absolute value (similar to how `array.max(axis=axis)` selects just the maximum value along a specific axis).

So for example (`absmax` is the desired function):

```
array = np.array([
    [ 5,  8,  2],
    [-7,  3,  0],
    [-2, -4, -1],
])
absmax(array, axis=0)  # [-7,  8,  2]
absmax(array, axis=1)  # [ 8, -7, -4]
```

I came up with the following implementation but it feels pretty clunky:

```
def absmax(a, *, axis):
    dims = list(a.shape)
    dims.pop(axis)
    indices = np.ogrid[tuple(slice(0, d) for d in dims)]
    argmax = np.abs(a).argmax(axis=axis)
    indices.insert((len(a.shape) + axis) % len(a.shape), argmax)
    return a[tuple(indices)]
```

So I'm wondering if there's a better / more concise way of achieving this functionality?

Comment: Previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655525/a-key-in-numpy-amax) to specifying a key to numpy.amax.  In this case key = abs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a simpler approach is to use `np.take_along_axis()` to implement a `lambda_max()` function that accept a `key` parameter:

```
def lambda_max(arr, axis=None, key=None, keepdims=False):
    if callable(key):
        idxs = np.argmax(key(arr), axis)
        if axis is not None:
            idxs = np.expand_dims(idxs, axis)
            result = np.take_along_axis(arr, idxs, axis)
            if not keepdims:
                result = np.squeeze(result, axis=axis)
            return result
        else:
            return arr.flatten()[idxs]
    else:
        return np.amax(arr, axis)
```

This can be used as follow:

```
print(lambda_max(array, 0, np.abs))
# [-7  8  2]
print(lambda_max(array, 1, np.abs))
# [ 8 -7 -4]
print(lambda_max(array, None, np.abs))
# 8
```

Comment: The `not keepdims` part should use `np.squeeze(result, axis=axis)` in order to retain other single-entry dimensions.

Comment: @a_guest Thanks for spotting this! Code is updated.

Answer (score 1):

In search of *compact-ness*, here's one that keeps dims -

```
def absmax(a, axis):
    s = np.array(a.shape)
    s[axis] = -1
    return np.take_along_axis(a,np.abs(a).argmax(axis).reshape(s),axis=axis)
```

Sample runs -

```
In [67]: a
Out[67]: 
array([[ 5,  8,  2],
       [-7,  3,  0],
       [-2, -4, -1]])

In [68]: absmax(a, axis=0)
Out[68]: array([[-7,  8,  2]])

In [69]: absmax(a, axis=1)
Out[69]: 
array([[ 8],
       [-7],
       [-4]])
```

---

If the extra dim look bother-some, add a reshape step to the output :

```
out = np.take_along_axis(a,np.abs(a).argmax(axis).reshape(s),axis=axis)
return out.reshape(np.delete(s,axis))
```

Sample runs on same input array -

```
In [89]: absmax(a, axis=0)
Out[89]: array([-7,  8,  2])

In [90]: absmax(a, axis=1)
Out[90]: array([ 8, -7, -4])
```

Comment: It seems like `np.squeeze(out, axis=axis)` is more suitable for removing that extra dimension (in terms of readability).